# Typings for ops off a Firebase Reference give error

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have a simple class which has a method `set` which abstracts the **set** functionality of Firebase. The set method is:

```
/** set a "value" in the database at a given path */
public async set<T = any>(path: string, value: T): Promise<void> {
  return this.ref(path)
    .set(value)
    .catch((e: any) =>
      this.handleError(e, "set", `setting value @ "${path}"`)
    );
}
```

This is fine from a typing standpoint if I use the standard client typings library:

```
import * as client from "@firebase/database";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
export type Reference = client.Reference;

/** Get a DB reference for a given path in Firebase */
public ref(path: string): Reference {
  return this._mocking
    ? this.mock.ref(path)
    : RealTimeDB.connection.ref(path);
}
```

It is also fine if I use the Admin API's reference typing:

```
export type Reference = client.Reference;
```

However, since this class is meant to be used by *both* the client and the server, I would like to define `Reference` as:

```
export type Reference = admin.database.Reference | client.Reference;
```

but when I do that VisualCode is still autocompleting my Reference correctly:

[image]

but at the same time I get an error indicator regardless of which method I choose from the reference:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((value: any, onComplete?: (a: Error) => any) => Promise) | ((newVal: any, onComplete?: (a:...' has no compatible call signatures.

What is causing this?